# How can I re-invoke a method that is in HUB? asp net core signalr

Tags: javascript, node.js, asp.net-core, signalr

Hello everyone I'm using aspnet core and signalr, and the problem with which I found was that I make a request
to the hub and the first time it enters the method and returns the values, but
and when I call the same method again I do not enter, this warning message comes out "Warning: No client method with the name 'mymethod' found signalr"
How can I solve this?, help please
this is my code
javascript

connection.invoke('mymethod', value1, value2);

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Hub

public async Task mymethod(string number, string another)

```
    {  //my operation  
    }
```

Comment: The information is not enough to reproduce your issue, is there any reproduceable  project through github?

Comment: Well, I was following the example of the official documentation and this example of
notifications with postgres
the problem is that once you invoke the method I can not invoke it again
because in the operation of the method the connection is waiting for new notifications
and for that reason it does not allow to invoke the method again
let me understand?

Comment: Share us the official document and reproducable project.

Comment: " https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio  "   " https://github.com/Harmen1969/SignalR-Postgresql-    "

Comment: public async Task mymethod(string number, string another)
    {  
 NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connStr);
            conn.Open();
 //my operation hire
 await Clients.All.SendAsync("Mymethod", valuesmethod);
            while (true)
            {
                conn.Wait();
            }
    }      this is my code in HUB